# Why is my nuget package push filtered out in VSTS (Azure Devops)

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, push

I have an azure DevOps pipeline who compile correctly and the log files indicate a successful "pack" into "D:\a\1\a\Packages\Rvi.LA.ObjetsMetiers.1.1.0.nupkg".

Concerning the nuget push step, I can see the following in the debug log :

```
2019-02-14T14:19:43.5995520Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:\a\1\a\Packages\RVI.LA.ObjetsMetiers*.nupkg'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9183973Z ##[debug]expanding braces
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9184020Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:/a/1/a/Packages/RVI.LA.ObjetsMetiers*.nupkg'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9209179Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\a\1\a\Packages'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9209259Z ##[debug]statOnly: 'false'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9212246Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\a\1\a\Packages'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9212452Z ##[debug]findOptions.allowBrokenSymbolicLinks: 'undefined'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9212597Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'undefined'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9212885Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'undefined'
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9223644Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\a\Packages (directory)
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9225732Z ##[debug]  D:\a\1\a\Packages\Rvi.LA.ObjetsMetiers.1.1.0.nupkg (file)
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9225814Z ##[debug]2 results
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9225888Z ##[debug]found 2 paths
```

So, it finds two results but strangely indicates "found 2 paths" when one of them is a file.  Anyway, it successfully finds the one who needs to be pushed and detect it is a file.

The problem is in the following part of the log :

```
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9225984Z ##[debug]applying include pattern
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9235322Z ##[debug]0 matches
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9235403Z ##[debug]0 final results
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9247396Z ##[warning]No packages matched the search pattern.
2019-02-14T14:19:44.9247569Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]No packages matched the search pattern.
```

It seems to exclude it with the include pattern who is "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Packages\$(NomNuspec)*.nupkg" and is translated to "D:\a\1\a\Packages\RVI.LA.ObjetsMetiers*.nupkg" in the log above.

I don't understand why it is not found.  Is there something who should hit me in the eye even though two persons looked at it many times?

Comment: It succeed with "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\*.nupkg", but I really need to be more specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

The package was packed as "Rvi.LA.ObjetsMetiers.1.1.0.nupkg", but the filter was "RVI" in uppercase.  I did see it, but thought "case sensitivity does not matter with a file name!", but it does.  The last update told me this is a real possibility.

I modified my nuget file to pack with "RVI.LA.ObjetsMetiers", not "Rvi.LA.ObjetsMetiers" and the original path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Packages\$(NomNuspec)*.nupkg" works as $(NomNuspec) is resolved with "RVI.LA.ObjetsMetiers" as stated above.

I will suggest to nuget to remove the "case-sensitiveness" as there is no way to have two files named "fileA.txt" and "FileA.txt" anyway.